# A Proof of The Recursion Theorem

Tags: logic, set-theory, induction, recursion

I am studying "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic" by Herbert Enderton, and I have a question about this theorem which is proved in 4 different steps in the book, and the proof is rather long. I was thinking of a much shorter proof, but I'm not sure if my proof is rigorous. It might have some errors.

**Recursion Theorem** Assume that the subset C of U is ***freely*** generated from B by f and g, where

$f: \mathbb U \times \mathbb U \to \mathbb U$
$g: \mathbb U \to \mathbb U$

Further assume that $\mathbb V$ is a set and F, G, and h functions such that

$h: \mathbb B \to \mathbb V$
$F: \mathbb V \times \mathbb V \to \mathbb V$
$G: \mathbb V \to \mathbb V$

Then, there is a unique function $\overline{h}:\mathbb C \to \mathbb V$ such that
(i) $\overline{h}(x) = h(x) \ \forall x \in B$
(ii) for x and y in C,
$\overline{h}(g(x)) = G(\overline{h}(x))$
$\overline{h}(f(x,y)) = F(\overline{h}(x), \overline{h}(y))$

By freely generated, we mean that the restrictions of f and g, $f_{C} , g_{C}$ are one to one, and the ranges of $f_C$, $g_C$ and the set B are pairwise disjoint.

**My Proof**
Define $ S = \{x \in U |\ \overline{h}(x)\ \text{is uniquely determined by (i) and (ii)}\}$.
We claim that S = C. if $x \in B$, then by (i) we have $\overline{h}(x) = h(x)$, and since the ranges of $f_C$, $g_C$, and B are mutually exclusive, $h(x)$ is the only possilbe assignment to $\overline{h}(x)$.Suppose $x, y \in \mathbb U $ such that $\overline{h}(x)$ and $\overline{h}(y)$ have been uniquely determined by (i) and (ii), then by (ii), we assinge $\overline{h}(f(x,y)) = F(\overline{h}(x), \overline{h}(y))$. Since F is one-to-one, and the ranges $f_C$, $g_C$, and B are disjoint, the assingment is unique. The same arguement works also for $\overline{h}(g(x))$ when  $\overline{h}(x)$ has been uniquely determined. Therefore, we have inductively proved that $S=C$.

Comment: First, your statement of the theorem is incorrect and incomplete -- for example, it should be $h:B\to V$ and $\overline{h}:C\to V$. Second, your attempted proof would at best show uniqueness of $\overline{h}$ but that's the easy part. How do we know that $\overline{h}$ exists as a function? You haven't actually constructed an object $\overline{h}$ for which it makes sense to write $\overline{h}(x)$ in your definition of $S$. Apart from that, there are other issues with your proof of uniqueness -- like $F$ need not be one-to-one.

Comment: I corrected the mistakes in the theorem, thank you, but I don't understand your point. I have defined S in a way so that it only contains elements such that $\overline{h}(x)$ is defined and is also unique. So, by showing that S=C we have proven that $\overline{h} $ is in fact a function defined on the set C. Would you please elaborate why my argument doesn't show that $\overline{h}$ is a function? @blargoner

Comment: I have actually constructed the object inductively though, right? because by (i), $\overline{h}$ is uniquely determined for $x \in B$, and inductively, I have constructed $\overline{h}$ for other elements of $C$. I also have pointed out why these seconds assignments also have to be unique.

Comment: No, you haven't. Your definition of $S$ does not make sense as currently written, for the reason I explained: you haven't actually exhibited an object $\overline{h}$, you've only referred to one as if it exists. This is why Enderton's proof is longer -- he takes a big union over approximating / partial functions in order to exhibit this object, and then show it has the required properties.

Comment: I know what you mean. I have also thought about the problem that $\overline{h}$ could actually take more than one value for one input and examples of that sort are also presented in the book before the proof. by $\overline{h}(x)$ in the definition of S, I mean the value that could be assigned to it by conditions (i) and (ii). I don't take for granted that  $\overline{h}(x)$ is already a function. So, if the notation is vague, maybe I should have written $ S=\{ x \in \mathbb C |  \overline{h} \text{ takes one and exactly one value}\}$

Comment: The potential problem is that for example, for example for an x in B, $\overline{h}(x)$ could take the value h(x) by (i) and at the same time there might be a y where x=g(y) and by (ii), $\overline{h}(x)= \overline{h}(g(y)) = G(\overline{h}(y))$, but as stated in the theorem, C is freely generated and the ranges of $f_C$, $g_C$, and B are mutually exclusive. So, a problem like that can no longer happen @blargoner

Comment: Even if you've shown there is at most one value that *could* be assigned, it doesn't mean you've put all those values together into an object $\overline{h}$ that is actually a function. Your proof is still incomplete. Enderton's is longer for good reason. Hopefully someone can explain this to you better in a longer answer, or you can talk to a professor. It's really important to see why your proof is not sufficient. Take care.

Comment: I wanted to be a little concise in statement. in this situation our only ways of assigning values to our object $\overline{h}$ are 1. $\overline{h}(x)= h(x)$ for x in B,
2. $\overline{h}(g(y))= G(\overline{h}(y))$, and 3. $\overline{h}(f(x,y)) = F(\overline{h}(x), \overline{h}(y))$ and by carefully considering the "freely generated" part, each part of the reasoning in the construction of $\overline{h}$ can be justified, right?

Comment: Thank you for your time and guidance. You're right I suspected my proof in the first place since the original one was a lot longer, but I'm not completely convinced why my proof is wrong. have a nice day